# How is it possible that O(1) constant time code is slower than O(n) linear time code?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

> "...It is very possible for O(N) code to run faster than O(1) code for specific inputs. Big O just describes the rate of increase."

According to my understanding:

- O(N) - Time taken for an algorithm to run based on the varying values of input N.
- O(1) - Constant time taken for the algorithm to execute irrespective of the size of the input e.g. `int val = arr[10000];`

Can someone help me understand based on the author's statement?

1. O(N) code run faster than O(1)?
2. What are the specific inputs the author is alluding to?
3. Rate of increase of what?

Comment: O(1) means that the process takes about the same amount of time regardless of the size of the input. O(N) means the time is proportional to the size of the input, so if you double the size of the input, you roughly double the time. O describes the way the time changes in relation to the size of the input to the process.

Comment: Example of O(1): `while (true) { ; }`. Example of O(n): `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { ; }`. Which one takes longer?

Comment: O(1) should take infinitely longer

Answer (score 6):

O(n) constant time can absolutely be faster than O(1) linear time. The reason is that constant-time operations are totally ignored in Big O, which is a measure of how fast an algorithm's complexity increases as input size *n* increases, and nothing else. It's a measure of growth rate, not running time.

Here's an example:

```
int constant(int[] arr) {
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
         total += arr[0];
    }

    return total;
}
   
int linear(int[] arr) {
    int total = 0;        

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        total += arr[i];
    }

    return total;
}
```

In this case, `constant` does a lot of work, but it's fixed work that will always be the same regardless of how large `arr` is. `linear`, on the other hand, appears to have few operations, but those operations are dependent on the size of `arr`.

In other words, as `arr` increases in length, `constant`'s performance stays the same, but `linear`'s running time increases linearly in proportion to its argument array's size.

Call the two functions with a single-item array like

```
constant(new int[] {1}); 
linear(new int[] {1});
```

and it's clear that `constant` runs slower than `linear`.

But call them like:

```
int[] arr = new int[10000000];

constant(arr);
linear(arr);
```

Which runs slower?

After you've thought about it, run the code given various inputs of *n* and compare the results.

---

Just to show that this phenomenon of `run time != Big O` isn't just for constant-time functions, consider:

```
void exponential(int n) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++) {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    }
}

void linear(int n) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Exercise (using pen and paper): up to which `n` does `exponential` run faster than `linear`?

Comment: Hmm!! Though the two functions  are operating on the same input, isn't it that you are comparing "apples to oranges" in that, one is operating on the entire array based on the input array size and the other is operating on a fixed element of an array 10000 times!!

Comment: That's right--Big O is a general description of *the rate of increase* of an algorithm and nothing else. It says nothing about the running time. Constant time can be extremely expensive and slow, but if it's a fixed amount of work, it's O(1) according to Big O.

Comment: If you still don't understand this, take the two algorithms and run them on an input size of 1 and time and compare them to see how long each takes. Then run them on an input of 100 and time the results. Try 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000 and time the results. Then report back your findings.

Comment: So in that case why do we even consider constant time when discussing algorithmic complexities? Why can't we compare the true "apples to apples" that is one that operates on the input? I mean O(n) vs O(n power 2) vs O(n log n)..?

Comment: We don't consider constant time in Big O. If you want to compare running times of two algorithms of the same or different complexity, you can certainly do that, but that's a different metric than Big O, which measures rate of growth and nothing else. If these two functions seem like apples and oranges, that's because they are two different complexity classes in Big O, namely O(1) and O(n). I don't follow how O(n) vs O(n^2) is any different than comparing O(1) to O(n), but I'll add that example.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you.

Comment: constant: 10000000 - 17ms
        linear:100 - 0ms;
        linear:1000 - 0ms
        linear:10000 - 0ms
        linear:100000 - 2ms
        linear:1000000 - 2ms
        linear:10000000 - 9ms
        linear:10000000 - 9ms

Comment: I don't follow--are you saying constant on 10000000 ran slower than linear? That doesn't seem correct. Here is my benchmark: https://repl.it/repls/DelightfulCriminalCoolingfan

Comment: That's correct. I ran this on my computer and those were the exact results

Comment: Right, but were your tests and benchmarking code correct/accurate? Did you run the repl and compare?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following scenario:

Op1) Given an array of length n where n>=10, print the first ten elements twice on the console. --> This is a constant time (O(1)) operation, because for any array of size>=10, it will execute 20 steps.

Op2) Given an array of length n where n>=10, find the largest element in the array. This is a constant time (O(N)) operation, because for any array, it will execute N steps.

Now if the array size is between 10 and 20 (exclusive), Op1 will be slower than Op2. But let's say, we take an array of size>20 (for eg, size =1000), Op1 will still take 20 steps to complete, but Op2 will take 1000 steps to complete.

That's why the big-o notation is about growth(rate of increase) of an algorithm's complexity